# TexStudio not finding scrbook.cls

Tags: koma-script, texstudio

I can not figure out why my LaTeX will not compile. I am using TexStudio and TexLive to manage my packages. I have made sure all my packages are up to date. I have also followed the [guide](http://www.tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf) posted on a previous question.

I am trying to follow along in LaTex Cookbook by Stefan Kottwitz. In it, he uses the `scrbook` package to create a book template. I have identified that I have that package.

[image: ScrBook]

When I try to compile, I get this error:

[image: error]

I have not made any adjustments to the build path or the TexLive settings.

This is where I call `scrbook`:

[image: Call scrbook]

Is there any easy solution that I am missing?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Study the error a bit closer, you'll see that it looks for a file called `<space>scrbook<space>.cls`, try removing the spaces around `scrbook`.

Comment: note that texstudio is not involved here that is just the editor you used to write the file,  the error is coming from tex and would be the same if you ran it on the commandline or from a different editor.

Comment: Wow, I knew it was going to be a simple, silly mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes across similar issues in the future, be sure you have closely examined the error. As @Torbjorn has pointed out to me, my error was looking for a file called `<space>scrbook.cls<space>`.

Simply remove the `<space>` and my `LaTeX` compiles.